# 'To Date' incrementing by one on every search in angular js (momentjs used to convert). How to prevent that?

Tags: angularjs, search, momentjs, date-range

I am using date range search in angular js and using moment.js. The 'To Date' increases by one date every time though I have set the time zone. Here is my code: 
           function getSearchDate(dateString) {
            var date = new Date(dateString);
            var dt =
                date.getFullYear() + '-' +
                ('00' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
                ('00' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
            return dt;
        }

```
     $scope.searchCampaigns = function () {

        if ($scope.campaignQry.fromDate) {
            $scope.campaignQry.fromDate = getSearchDate($scope.campaignQry.fromDate) + 'T00:00:00.000Z';
        }
        if ($scope.campaignQry.toDate) {
            $scope.campaignQry.toDate = getSearchDate($scope.campaignQry.toDate) + 'T23:59:59.000Z';
        }

        getAllCampaigns();
    };


         function getDate(dateString) {
        if (!dateString) {
            return 'N/A';
        }
        return moment(dateString).format('MMM DD, YYYY, h:mm A');
    }
```

[initially](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrWiy.png)

[after search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpe7v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I converted the date string to Date object and concatenate it with T00:00:00.000+0530. Don't concatenate with T00:00:00.000Z. (i.e. use exact time zone of country). Lastly, return the moment date object.